# How to detect "buzz" components in audio by frequency domain analysis

Tags: audio, stft, audio-processing, cepstral-analysis

I am trying to detect the amplitude, frequency and phase of the dominant "buzz" in an audio signal. By "buzz" I mean a periodic signal with sharp edges. For example, an impulse train or a square wave.

In the frequency domain, "buzz" signals have a fundamental f0 and harmonics at integer intervals n * f0. Unlike other harmonic tones, there is a linear phase relationship between "buzz" harmonics: that's what gives it sharp edges.

So far I have tried autocorrelation and cepstrum approaches. These are great at detecting harmonic signals, but are distracted by other signal components, for example in music. So I think I have to check each autocorrelation peak to see whether there is phase coherency between harmonics of the corresponding f0.

I have a feeling that there is an elegant mathematical method involving an FFT pair that I'm missing here. The key would seem to be detecting the phase relationship between harmonics, and their regular spacing, in one pass. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please clarify if your "buzz" is constant or changing in time (in magnitude and frequency). If changing, what is your desired time and frequency resolution?

Comment: Please describe the application and the requirements. This is a VERY complicated problem and a huge amount of person hours has already been spend on this specifically in the area of manufacturing testing of loudspeakers. There is no easy solution and so it would be helpful to understand what you need it for and how good it needs to be.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the sound you want to detect, and some sounds you want to discriminate it from?

Comment: Examples might be a heavily distorted bass guitar, or raspy, hoarse-sounding speech.